Reading with LOCAL_QUORUM but got "ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ALL"
We are seeing read timed out exceptions in the application when we are trying to fetch the data with consistency level LOCAL_QUORUM.
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: \
  Cassandra timeout during read query at consistency ALL \
  (4 responses were required but only 3 replica responded)

Above exception we are not seeing for all read operation for some calls we are seeing the exception.

Cassandra version : 3.11.0
Driver version : 3.3.1
Data centers : 2
No.of nodes in each DC : 10
Replication Factor : 2

Want to know why it is taking consistency level as ALL, even though we specified it as LOCAL_QUORUM.

Where are you seeing this error message? Some prepared statement somewhere is probably set to use ALL, is my guess.

we are seeing this exception in Application logs. we are using local_quorum in the prepared stmt not ALL.
As mentioned in the description, in some reads we are seeing not all reads.

The ALL consistency is not being used to perform the regular read request by the application. As you stated, the application requests data with LOCAL_QUORUM.
What is more likely is that a read-repair is getting triggered which is a read with a consistency of ALL so that any replica that is inconsistent gets repaired. The read-repair gets triggered for a percentage of reads because the table being read has a non-zero read-repair chance:
CREATE TABLE ...
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (...)
) WITH ...
    AND read_repair_chance = #.#
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = #.#
    ...

Note that background repair has been removed in Cassandra 4.0 (CASSANDRA-13910) so those table options are no longer valid.
As a side note, C* 3.11.0 was released in 2017. There have been hundreds of fixes to known issues released since then so consider upgrading your cluster to latest 3.11 release (at the time of writing, C* 3.11.17 released in April 2024). Cheers!
